# Xcode 15 UIKit Preview FailedToLaunchAppError: Failed to launch error

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, preview, xcode15

I'm trying to preview UIKit view using #Preview macro in Xcode 15, but got this error

```
== PREVIEW UPDATE ERROR:

    FailedToLaunchAppError: Failed to launch
    
    ==================================
    
    |  RemoteHumanReadableError: The operation couldn’t be completed. Transaction failed. Process failed to launch. (process launch failed)
    |  
    |  BSTransactionError (1):
    |  ==error-reason: process launch failed
    |  ==transaction: <FBApplicationProcessLaunchTransaction: 0x600003b287e0>
    |  ==precipitating-error: Error Domain=FBProcessExit Code=64 "The process failed to launch." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The process failed to launch., BSErrorCodeDescription=launch-failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c1ad90 {Error Domain=RBSRequestErrorDomain Code=5 "Launch failed." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Launch failed., NSUnderlyingError=0x600000c1aee0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=111 "Unknown error: 111" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Launchd job spawn failed}}}}}
    |  ==error-description: Process failed to launch.
    |  ==NSLocalizedFailureReason: Transaction failed. Process failed to launch. (process launch failed)
```

Code I'm trying to preview on iPhone 15

```
import UIKit

final class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

@available(iOS 17, *)
#Preview {
    SomeViewController()
}
```

Comment: Did you found solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our project could not initially be debugged using the simulator in Apple silicon, so it could not be previewed.

After the arm64 architecture is excluded from each target:
[image]
the simulator works, but `#Preview` still doesn't work and gives the same error message as your question: failed to launch(I'm pretty sure we got exactly the same error).

After trying various methods:

- deleting all the code in didFinishLaunch
- deleting the Preview cache
- deleting the Simulator cache
- deleting DerivedData
- restarting Xcode
- restarting Mac

all failed，Until we remembered how to build an App using Rosetta simulator:
[image]

Use the Rosetta simulator as the build target and set the preview to be the same device,A miracle happened：
[image]

It is important for us to:
We turned off auto-refresh canvas to make Preview finally work.
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Using Rosetta targets worked for me.